# Redshift delete duplicate records but keep latest

Tags: duplicates, amazon-redshift, sql-delete

### Current Table

```sql
select * from currentTable;
```

```sql
select * from PG_TABLE_DEF where tablename='currenttable';
 schemaname |  tablename   |        column         |         type          | encoding | distkey | sortkey | notnull
------------+--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------+---------
 public     | currenttable | kafkaoffset           | integer               | az64     | f       |       0 | t
 public     | currenttable | operation             | character varying(25) | lzo      | f       |       0 | t
 public     | currenttable | othertablepk          | integer               | az64     | f       |       0 | t
 public     | currenttable | othertableorderstatus | character varying(25) | lzo      | f       |       0 | t
```

```sql
| kafkaOffset | operation | otherTablePK  | otherTableOrderStatus |
|:------------|----------:|:-------------:|-----------------------:
| 1024        | CREATE    |  23           | Cooking
| 1025        | UPDATE    |  23           | Shipped
| 1026        | UPDATE    |  23           | Delivered
| 1027        | CREATE    |  51           | Cooking
| 1028        | UPDATE    |  51           | Shipped
| 1029        | CREATE    |  52           | Cooking
```

I want to dedupe my current table to keep only the latest record(by `kafkaOffset`) based on the `otherTablePk`.

### Deduped Table (Expected Result)

```sql
select * from currentTable;
```

```sql
| kafkaOffset | operation | otherTablePK  | otherTableOrderStatus |
|:------------|----------:|:-------------:|-----------------------:
| 1026        | UPDATE    |  23           | Delivered
| 1028        | UPDATE    |  51           | Shipped
| 1029        | CREATE    |  52           | Cooking
```

### Solution-1: USING `InnerJoin` and `max`

MYSQL like query in redshift using `inner join` and `max`. [More Info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107167/mysql-delete-duplicate-records-but-keep-latest)

```sql
DELETE
FROM currentTable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT max(kafkaOffset) AS lastOffset,
          otherTablePk AS otherTablePkID
   FROM currentTable
   WHERE otherTablePkID IN
       (SELECT otherTablePk
        FROM currentTable
        GROUP BY otherTablePk
        HAVING count(*) > 1)
   GROUP BY otherTablePk) lastTable ON lastTable.otherTablePkID = currentTable.otherTablePkID
WHERE current_table.kafkaOffset < lastTable.lastOffset;
```

### Solution-2: Using `USING` and doing Self Join.

```sql
DELETE from currentTable t1 
JOIN currentTable t2 USING (otherTablePK) 
WHERE t1.kafkaOffset < t2.kafkaOffset
```

### Solution-3: Using `TEMP` table and surgical deletes

As explained in this [blog](https://medium.com/@elliotchance/removing-duplicate-data-in-redshift-45a43b7ae334) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582261/deleting-duplicates-rows-from-redshift), but the use case is little different here. We need to **delete everything but keep the latest**., doing max makes the query slow.

All the solutions above would be slow in Redshift, it being a columnar storage. Please suggest what would be the fastest way to do this operation in Redshift?

Comment: Do you have proper indexes on the table? Please check once

Comment: I have not put any index as it is Redshift. I just wanted to know the performance in big tables. This is a test table. Have not gone into production yet.

Comment: Without index it will perform slow. Anyhow you can use sub query approach which is mentioned in @Jonathan Jacobson's answer should be faster comparatively.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the table DDL. Otherwise it's all speculation.

Talking about speculation, please try this untested query (I don't have Redshift):

```
DELETE FROM currentTable
WHERE kafkaOffset IN (
    SELECT kafkaOffset
    FROM (
        SELECT kafkaOffset
             , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY otherTablePK ORDER BY kafkaOffset DESC) rn
        FROM currentTable
    ) t
    WHERE rn > 1
);
```

Comment: Posted the table DDL. kafkaOffset is the primary and otherTablePrimaryKey is the primary key in another table. This is a temp table which i want to dedupe to finally insert in the otherTable.

Comment: @AlokKumarSingh then don't delete at all! Just select the rows that you want.