# Deleting completely identical duplicates from db

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We have a table in our db with copied data that has completely duplicated many rows. Because the id is also duplicated there is nothing we can use to select just the duplicates. I tried using a limit to only delete 1 but redshift gave a syntax error when trying to use limit.

Any ideas how we can delete just one of two rows that have completely identical information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use select distinct to create a new table.  Then either truncate & copy the data, or drop the original table and rename the new table to the original name:

```
create table t2 as select distinct * from t;
truncate t;
insert into t from select * from t2;
drop table t2;
```

2. Add column a column with unique values.  `identity(seed, step)` looks interesting.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is one option. I'm a bit worried since the table is 532 million rows though

Comment: Yeah, I figured, added a 2nd option

Comment: what would that second option query look like? I've never used row_number(). Does it work with redshift?

Comment: or just get some arbitrary incrementing number using whatever language I'm using?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it in app code.    See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html

Comment: I think I will do a variation of your first suggestion. I will use my app code, load each duplicate then delete all of them by id and reinsert just one row. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582261/deleting-duplicates-rows-from-redshift